# Nonlinear mixed model without random effects structure specification

Tags: r, mixed-models, non-linear-regression, nlme

I would like to fit a nonlinear model just with the fixed structure specification using nlme R package.

```
model <- nlme(y ~ Asym/(1+exp((xmid-x)/scal)),
                      data = data,
                      fixed = list(Asym + xmid + scal ~ treatment))
                      #random =  Asym ~ 1|subject)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = paste("~", paste(nVal, collapse = "/"))) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~ 
   ^
```

Is there a way to circunvent this issue? Any advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want the `gnls()` function (also from the `nlme` package) with the `params=` argument rather than `fixed=`. Try this:

```
model <- gnls(y ~ Asym/(1+exp((xmid-x)/scal)),
                  data = data,
                  params = list(Asym + xmid + scal ~ treatment),
                  start= ...)
```

FWIW, if you're really fitting a logistic (and this isn't just a simplified example of what you want to do), fitting might be faster/more robust with the `SSlogis()` self-starting function in place of your explicit formula ...